# Rspec.NoMethodError: undefined method `expect' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I try to test 'cancan' gem.And when I running rspec, in line

```
expect(ability).to be_able_to(:destroy, Project.new(:user => user))
```

shell show me an error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `expect' for main:Object
```

this is ability_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
  require "cancan/matchers"

  describe Ability do
    it "user has ability" do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      ability = Ability.new(user)
      expect(ability).to be_able_to(:destroy, Project.new(:user => user))
    end
  end
```

**UPD**

```
2.1.5 :004 >     expect(ability).to be_able_to(:destroy, Project.new(:user => user))
NoMethodError: undefined method `expect' for main:Object
    from (irb):4
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2.1.5 :005 >
```

**2UPD**

```
weare138@weare138-P5K-SE:~/timonin$ bundle exec rspec spec/models/ability_spec.rb
/home/weare138/timonin/spec/models/ability_spec.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Ability (NameError)
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

ability.rb

```
    class Ability
      include CanCan::Ability

      def initialize(user)
        user ||= User.new
        if user.admin?
          can :manage, :all
        else
          can :read, :all
        end
    end
 end
```

how fix?

sorry for my bad English

Comment: Can you show the full backtrace?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run the `expect` command from a console (or at least, that's not the usual way).

Instead, to run the test run

```
bundle exec rspec path/to/ability_spec.rb
```

Or if you want to run all your tests:

```
bundle exec rspec .
```

Comment: in this way does not work you are talking, show the same error

Comment: Looking at your update2, now you are getting a different error: The expect method is found, but the Ability class is not found

Comment: oh, sorry.I didn't notice.How write the correct test?

Comment: My guess is that your `app/models/ability.rb` does not exist. Check the docs at https://github.com/ryanb/cancan there you will find what to do.

Comment: the problem is that this model ability.rb is exists :)

Comment: maybe you don't load Rails (I mean all classes from your app). If you use the last RSpec you should `require 'rails_helper'` (which loads your app)